# wget : how to get a directory to a specify directory

Tags: linux, bash, wget

The command I am using is:

```
wget -r -nH ftp://some.domain.com/home/work/test/* -P ./my
```

The output directory becomes:

```
./my/home/work/test/*
```

How can I make it to just `./my/*`?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--cut-dirs` option. In Your case, `--cut-dirs=3` to cut off home, work and test.

Answer (score 2):

See the [fine manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/) for a description of the [`--cut-dirs` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory-Options.html#index-cut-directories-70).